# managing user accounts by group name, username and last login linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I created a script called monitornsuaccounts.sh that should append its output file to useraccountstatus.log. useraccountstatus.log is in the directory /var/local/nsu/logs/.

The output of this script should state every username and the following information about each username: username, last login, user home directory and associated groups. Preferably there should be columns with each information.

The command I use for the usernames is sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep ‘/home’. Last is to find the last login of each user. Groups is to the find the group of each user. When I run the command, the output file only shows the data I need for my current user rather than all users. Any recommendations that anyone has would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
usernames=sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep ‘/home’
echo “$usernames” > /home/daniel/names.txt
mlast=$(cat names.txt | xargs -n1 last)
mgroup=$(cat names.txt | xargs -n1 groups)
cat names.txt > /var/local/nsu/logs/useraccountstatus.log
echo “$mlast” >>/var/local/nsu/logs/useraccountstatus.log
echo “$mgroup” >>/var/local/nsu/logs/useraccountstatus.log
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in your script.

1. Your definition of users. Are you sure that this is what you want? For example: root does not have a directory under /home.
2. Watch your quotes. `cat /etc/passwd | grep ‘/home’` returns nothing, while `cat /etc/passwd | grep 'home'` returns a list of stanzas in /etc/passwd
3. You'll probably want just a list of usernames, not a list of stanzas. Something along the line of

   ```
   cat /etc/passwd | grep 'home' | sed 's/:.*//'
   ```
4. Why `sudo` in `sudo cat /etc/passwd`?
5. Look at your assignment in the

   ```
   usernames=sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep ‘/home’
   ```

   This does not make sense. You might try to do a

   ```
   usernames=`sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep '/home'| sed 's/:.*//'`
   ```

And that is just the first line of the script.

Anyway, if your script does not work as intended, you will need to do some debugging. First question, especially if you are inexperienced, is "do the commands that I write give the result that I expect?" So in your case, you should have tried `cat /etc/passwd | grep ‘/home’` and you would have seen that it does not give you the expected results. Even with the correct quotes, you'll get a list of stanzas, which is also not what you expected. Have you looked at `/home/daniel/names.txt` and was the content of the file what you wanted? I guess not: it was empty.

Just a quick hint, to get you started in the right direction (although there are still some issues and pepole might object to the backtics)

```
#!/bin/bash
usernames=`sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep '/home'| sed 's/:.*//'`
mlast=`echo $usernames | xargs -n1 last`
mgroup=`echo $usernames| xargs -n1 groups`
echo $usernames > /var/local/nsu/logs/useraccountstatus.log
echo "$mlast" >>/var/local/nsu/logs/useraccountstatus.log
echo "$mgroup" >>/var/local/nsu/logs/useraccountstatus.log
```

You will want to polish this and make the output more useful.